# How do the qinggong monk's spell-like ability ki powers interact with the sensei's Mystic Wisdom feature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, monk

The *[Sensei](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/sensei/)* monk archetype allows, from 6th level onwards, a monk to use the ability

> **Mystic Wisdom (Su)**
>   At 6th level, a sensei may use his advice ability when spending points from his ki pool to activate a class ability (using the normal actions required for each) in order to have that ability affect one ally within 30 feet rather than the sensei himself....

Does a *[Qinggong](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/qinggong-monk/)* monk's spell-like ability ki-powers - *taken in replacement of class features, such as trading* "Slow Fall" *for the SLA* "True Strike" - count as a *"class ability"* for the purposes of the *"Mystic Wisdom"* ability?

And if so, does having the ability *"affect one ally within 30 feet rather than the sensei himself"* mean the spell-effects of the SLA affect the ally, or would they just gain the ability to cast it themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all abilities gained by your class, that aren't spells themselves, count as *class abilities*, including the spell-like abilities of the [Qinggong monk archetype](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/qinggong-monk/). Abilities such as Feather Step, Gaseous Form or even Barkskin are all class abilities of your monk class, once learned.

Here I have to link the [(in)famous Sean K. Reynolds post](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ln8z?Can-a-Life-Oracle-with-Channeling-take#30) explaining about "if it quacks like a duck", which should clarify what is considered a "class ability".

When *affecting* one ally, it means the ability effects will affect your ally instead of yourself, for abilities such as Barkskin, Gaseous Form or True Strike, which normally may only affect the caster.

Just keep in mind:

> These abilities function at the sensei’s level and last 1 round.

Comment: This combo of features is a pain! Kudos for taking it on! To be clear, a level 7 the qinggong sensei monk takes a standard action to spend 1 point from his *ki* pool to activate the spell-like ability *true strike* then takes a move action to start a bardic performance to… um… *transfer* the *effect* of the spell-like ability to the ally. Is that accurate? If that's the case, whose clock is the *true strike* effect on, the monk's or the ally's? What if the monk's performance ends—like because he dies or is knocked unconscious—before the *true strike* effect is used? Can the ally still use it?

Comment: @HeyICanChan while the formating in the SRD is kind of weird, this paragraph is just after all those abilities of the sensei class: *"These abilities function at the sensei’s level and last 1 round."*

Comment: Cool. (My investigation showed that there were exactly *five* Paizo messageboard threads mentioning both archetypes, but, as both archetypes are difficult to spell, it wouldn't surprise me to learn that other misspelled ones lurk elsewhere!)